# Node.js on SSH server

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am new with SSH. I have SSH server with Cent OS and I need create Node.js program use Express. After install Node.js I run node and next tried connection to server in browser with this URL:
`http://IP_ADDRESS:3000/`. But get error `Can't connect to server`.

Sorry for my stupid question, but help me with this problem. What I need do for send request to node.js server.

Comment: There is not enough detail in this question. Also, it's likely that your server's firewall is preventing you from accessing port 3000 from its external IP.

Comment: Liam Gray, I love you! I find article how open port 3000 http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll make it an official answer to your Q :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is quite vague, it could be that your server's firewall is preventing you from accessing port 3000 from its external IP.

Article used by OP for their platform: http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html

Comment: I is not my own server, I know only login&pass and OS =)